Java casting variable to Double when using ternary operator
If I using ternary operator to assign an Object variable with Double or Integer value, it being casted to double for some reason.
No matter what I do with order and condition of ternary operator parameters, it still be Double for some reason. Here's few examples:
final Object n = false ? Double.parseDouble("2") : Integer.parseInt("1"); 
System.out.println(n + " " + n.getClass()); // Output is "1.0 class java.lang.Double"

final Object n = false ? Integer.parseInt("1") : Double.parseDouble("2");
System.out.println(n + " " + n.getClass()); // Output is "2.0 class java.lang.Double"

final Object n = true ? Integer.parseInt("1") : Double.parseDouble("2");
System.out.println(n + " " + n.getClass()); // Output is "1.0 class java.lang.Double"

final Object n = true ? Integer.valueOf("1") : Double.valueOf("2");
System.out.println(n + " " + n.getClass()); // Output is "1.0 class java.lang.Double"

As you can see in the last example I've tried to use valueOf instead of parse*, which returns non-primitive types (so no reason to cast them to assign an Object var???), but result still be the same. The question is why java casting value exactly to Double, when it's definitely not relying on parameters order, which of those are chosen, and need of casting?

"so no reason to cast them to assign an Object var" What? Object cannot store a primitive. Primitives will always be boxed if you assign them to an Object variable.

double is mightier than int, so in a fight, the former will win. That's my guess and I wouldn't like to have to search the language spec to see what the 'rules' actually are on the above. Decompile it and look out for the i2d instruction. valueOf is the rational code here btw

@ElliottFrisch: No, if it was hitting that case, the int would be boxed to an Integer, and remain that way instead of getting converted to a Double. It's actually hitting the case right above: "Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands. Note that binary numeric promotion performs unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) and value set conversion (§5.1.13)."

This question is similar to: Unexpected type resulting from the ternary operator. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The type returned by the conditional operator is determined by the Java Specification depending on the second and third operands' types.
In your first and third case the second operand is an int, the third a double. If you look at Table 15.25-B. Conditional expression type (Primitive 3rd operand, Part II) in the linked spec, the result of such a conditional operation is defined as bnp(int,double), which means it applies binary numeric promotion of an int result to double that then gets autoboxed to a Double since you're assigning the result to an Object.
In your second and fourth case we have a Integer and a Double. Table 15.25-D. Conditional expression type (Reference 3rd operand, Part II) tells us that the return type is bnp(Integer,Double) so, again, a Double.

At the section Table 15.25-C. Conditional expression type (Reference 3rd operand, Part I) we see that if we have second parameter of type Double and third an Integer, we should have bnp(Double,Integer), which means we should have an Integer as result? If so, please check the first case, where it looks like it doesn't work

The first case are a double and an int, not a Double and an Integer, so it returns a double which then gets autoboxed to a Double

@FedericoklezCulloca I've replaced parse* with valueOf to get Double and Integer and result still the same

Please instead of saying "I've replaced" show the full example and the actual result you get.

@FedericoklezCulloca
System.out.println(n + " " + n.getClass()); // 2.0 class java.lang.Double```

Again 2nd is Double, third is Integer, resulting in bnp(Double,Integer), that is Double (https://imgur.com/a/BQ1UdAf)

bnp(Double, Integer) is actually double, not Double, but then it gets autoboxed for the assignment to Object.
